# Bootstrap Carousel not working in IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, carousel

I have a carousel that fades into the next slide. I works fine in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't seem to fade in or out in IE. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Here is some code similar to mine:

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
 opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-moz-transition-property: opacity;
-o-transition-property: opacity;
 transition-property: opacity;
 }
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner .item {
   height: 100%;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: silver;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: orange;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#carousel').carousel();
```

Comment: What version, did you happen to read the docs? -> Transition animations not supported in Internet Explorer 8 & 9
Bootstrap exclusively uses CSS3 for its animations, but Internet Explorer 8 & 9 don't support the necessary CSS properties. Thus, there are no slide transition animations when using these browsers. We have intentionally decided not to include jQuery-based fallbacks for the transitions.

Comment: I was testing in IE 11. Can you recommend some workarounds to make it work in IE? Also, why was it intentional not to include jQuery fallbacks for the transitions?